# how to test a static library project with codeblocks and target definition

Tags: c, project-management, codeblocks

I have a static library project and now i want to test some functions. To achive my goal i added a new target of type console, because when i try to "run" my library i get right the message "...select an host application to run...", then i added to this target a test file, test.c, that use some function.

From my knowledge, targets are different way to process sources file, so the release target produces a *.a file, and the debug target produces other.

```
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

struct object_geometry *load_ObjModel(char *fileName);

int main()
{
    printf("Buongiorno!");
    load_ObjModel("../dado.obj");
    return 0;
}
```

After writing test.c, i select the last created target and during debugging something doesn't work, because i can't use the modality "go line by line", or putting breakpoint in the above code, so:

- how can i debug my library, without the creation fo a new project?
- what's a target in codeblocks?
- (other useful related informations are appreciated)